# AWS Elemental MediaPackage Time-shifted is not working 404 error

Tags: aws-mediapackage

In AWS Elemental MediaPackage, I am trying enable time-shifted viewing as below reference link:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/mediapackage/latest/ug/time-shifted.html

But an HTTP error 404 occured. How can I fix it? Please help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use Time-Shifted viewing on Elemental MediaPackage if start-over window is configured on your end-point. Looking at your description it looks like MediaPackage could not find a segment to satisfy your request. It may be due to one of the following :

1. Start Over window was configured after the end-point was created.
2. No ingest into the MediaPackage channel for the timestamps you requested.

Inorder to find out the reason behind this issue, I'll need the channel arn or the playback URL along with the timestamps when you made this request. Can you please provide these details to take a look ?